# Empty list of data packages from download API

Tags: ordnance-survey

I am trying to obtain a list of data packages as specified in [the downloads API documentation](https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/downloads/gettingStarted).

When I send the request:
https://api.os.uk/downloads/v1/dataPackages?key=MY-API-KEY

I receive an empty list [].

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need to use the api key see https://osdatahub.os.uk/support#generateApiKey

Comment: I am using the API Key but I would expect my request to return the list of data packages but I get an empty list instead.